# How do I forbid avx512 while compile a program with -static option?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, glibc, avx512

I have a program that can compile at local machine and need to run at remote server, and it's not allowed to be compiled at remote server.

Now cpus of these local machine all have AVX512 instruments set, but remote server doesn't. Generally speaking, we can use `-march=x86-86, -march=core-avx2, -mo-avx512f` etc. to try to forbidden avx512 instrument, but there is a problem is that, the version of glibc at local machine is higher than remote, so I need to compile the program statically.  If not, program will dump at remote server because glibc's version is not lower(and it's not allowed to update the glibc at remote server too,sadly), but when I compile with `-static`, I will find that the program have AVX512 instruments. (the way i find AVX512 is to use a tool named elfx86exts to check what instrument the program have).

Is there some ways to compile a program that be able to run at remote server?

I'm sorry that my English is not so well, if there is some points that I didn't express clearly, please ask me.Thank you all.

I tried some compile option combinations.

1. -static -march=x86-64.
2. + -mno-avx512f -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512idma and other -mno-avx512** options.
3. -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -march=x86-64
4. -march=x86-64. -mno-avx512**

1,2,3 will fail at the ci of avx512 test, 4 has no avx512, but will have conflict of version of glibc.

Comment: It *could* be that the compiler generates multiple versions of some code, and checks for AVX512 at runtime. The fact that it is present in the executable doesn't *have* to mean that it is used at all target machines.

Comment: @BoP: Or that `-static` links glibc functions that have AVX-512 versions which won't execute on non-AVX512 CPUs.  glibc `memcpy` has an AVX-512 version that uses masking for 256-bit vectors to handle odd lengths more efficiently.  (But the dispatch mechanism is based on hooking the dynamic linker symbol resolver, which doesn't happen with static linking.) I just tried it with a trivial program that just calls `memcpy(b, a, argc*4)` so it doesn't expand inline, and indeed `__memset_avx512_unaligned_erms` got linked, along with many `..._evex_...` versions of other funcs, and an `ifunc` resolver

Comment: So a static scan for AVX-512 instructions is too simplistic and will flag any executable that statically links a modern version of glibc.  Perhaps you can exclude by function name?  Many (perhaps all?) of glibc's AVX-512-using functions have `_evex` in their name.  (That's the name of the 4-byte machine-code prefix for AVX-512 instructions, vs. VEX for AVX1/2).  Or perhaps it's possible to build a version of static glibc without any of the AVX-512 versions included at all, if there's an `#ifdef` or configure option for them.  Or perhaps use an alternative libc like MUSL?

Comment: Are you able/allowed to downgrade gcc/glibc at your local machine?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Use a docker with the same glibc as on the remote machine. Never ever use `-static`. It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

> but there is a problem is that, the version of glibc at local machine is higher than remote, so I need to compile the program statically.

The solution to this problem is *not* to link statically; it is to link against *appropriate* for the target version of `libc` (e.g. by building inside a docker container, or by pointing the compiler at an alternate `libc` installation).

Contrary to popular belief, statically-linked binaries almost never work (correctly) when moved to a different machine.

Comment: What kind of failure modes are you referring to?  The kernel APIs / ABIs that libc itself uses are pretty stable, so are you talking about programs that want to communicate with other programs using binary messages or something?  Like X11, or modern desktop protocols?

Comment: @PeterCordes Any program which uses `nsswitch.conf` or locales is likely to break in "interesting" ways.